# How to use ORDER BY CHARINDEX() along with UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use `ORDER BY CHARINDEX()` with `UNION`?
What I want is like:

```
select  Id,Name from A where Name like '%Raspberry%' 
Union
select  Id,Name from B where Name like '%Raspberry%' 
order by CHARINDEX('Raspberry',Name)
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Now what is the problem

Comment: An `order by` applies to the entire union, so the query as you post it should work

Comment: but not working its showing error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
"

Comment: @AnsuVerma check my answer, It fixes error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Common Table Expression**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) will help you:

```
with cte as (
select  Id,Name, CHARINDEX('Raspberry', Name) ci from #t1 where Name like '%Raspberry%' 
Union
select  Id,Name, CHARINDEX('Raspberry', Name) ci from #t2 where Name like '%Raspberry%' 
) 
select  Id, Name
from cte
order by ci
```

**<kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/014923/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

AS you mentioned the problem is you have to select the column present in order by if you are using `UNION`. Try this.

```
select  Id,Name,CHARINDEX('Raspberry',Name) as order_col 
from A 
where Name like '%Raspberry%' 
Union
select  Id,Name,CHARINDEX('Raspberry',Name) as order_col 
from B 
where Name like '%Raspberry%' 
order by order_col
```

Comment: This will select additional column order_col, isn't It? To avoid It need to pass It to subquery or create CTE, nevermind, result is correct.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas - yes, but it may not be a problem.